# Made a lock file but multiprocessing breaks it

Tags: python, locking, python-multiprocessing

I made a lock file function for my script so that only one instance will run at once. Everything should work fine, but if I'm using multiprocessing it gives the error `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`, even though it's only used within the main process.

I've been trying to fix it for hours with no luck, I'm wondering if anyone else might be able to suggest a fix? I've wrapped virtually every part in `try/except KeyboardInterrupt`, running `p.terminate()` to force close the process before deleting the file, with and without the `damon` flag, passing `lock` to the main script and deleting earlier at the end of the function, etc, and I'm totally out of ideas now.

Edit: I've just come across the same problem again in a different case (absolute pain to work around, in the end I had to figure out another way of doing things), so still curious if anyone could shed any light on the issue.

Lock class:

```
import os
OSError = FileNotFoundError = WindowsError = IOError

class Lock(object):
    """Stop two versions of the script from being loaded at the same time."""
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.closed = False

    def __enter__(self):
        #Create file if it doesn't exist (probably need to rewrite with os.exists instead)
        try:
            with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
                pass
        except IOError:
            pass

        #Check if file is locked, or create a new one
        try:
            os.remove(self.filename)
        except IOError:
            self._file = None
        else:
            self._file = open(self.filename, 'w')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()

    def __bool__(self):
        return self._file is not None
    __nonzero__ = __bool__

    def close(self):
        """Close the locked file."""
        if not self.closed:
            if self._file is not None:
                self._file.close()
            self.closed = True
            os.remove(self.filename)
```

Code it doesn't work with (starts working if you comment out `p.start()`):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def main():
    p = Process(target=background)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        print time.time()

def background():
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Lock('C:/Users/Peter/Python/lock.tmp') as lock:
        if lock:
            main()
        else:
            print 'already running'
```

If it is closed or you hit ctrl+c, you get this message, and the file remains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Python\test.py", line 77, in <module>
    print 'already running'
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Python\test.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Python\test.py", line 55, in close
    os.remove(self.filename)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/Peter/Python/lock.tmp'
```

Like I put above, I tried a ton of variations but nothing seemed to work. Does Python not instantly close files, and is there a way to force it to?

Comment: what does your `Lock` class wanna achieve by removing the lock file? `with Lock('') as lock: if lock:` is always true. why not use this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock/

Comment: It's only to clean up the file, but unfortunately the same issue persists with the filelock.py file in `WindowsFileLock._release()`

Comment: you could show an example of how `filelock` package used.

Comment: I used it as the example says you should, but removed the try/except from the file deletion to test it. It was still unable to delete the file if a second process had been spawned

Comment: without seeing the code, I can not imagine what your issue is.

Comment: Here's an example, I added in Queue so the background process would exit. It will never delete the lock file it creates - https://pastebin.com/pXYJ2zuH

Comment: If the try/except code in `filelock.py` is removed, I also get `WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'lock.temp'`

Comment: why do you want to delete the lock file on disk?

Comment: doesn't the code snippet you pasted accomplished your goal?

Comment: You asked that before lol, I want the file cleaned up at the end of the script, that's the thing my own script was unable to do :P